# Oracle SQL ||ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle

I was trying to figure out those name whose salary is lesser than their best friend's salary ,I had three tables student(name,id) ,friends(Id,friend_id) and packages(id,salary).I tried a way of joining all three tables and then self join ,then comparison of salary .what is wrong in this solution?

```
select s.name
from   (
         select *
         from   students
                join friends on students.id=friends.id
                join packages on friends.id=packages.id
       ) as s
       join (
         select *
         from   students
                join friends on students.id=friends.id
                join packages on friends.id=packages.id
       ) as b
where  s.salary<b.salary
and    s.Friend_ID=b.ID
order by b.salary;
```

I was expection an output displaying names of such students whose friend got higher salary package order by their friends salary;

I am getting this result

```
(select \* from students join friends on students.id=friends.id join packages on friends.id=packages.id) as s join (select \* from students join friends on students.id=friends.id join packages on friends.id=packages.id) as b where s.salary\<b.salary and s.Friend_ID=b.ID order by b.salary
\*
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Comment: You do not need subqueries for this query. Just use as many joins in a single query as you need with table aliases if one table plays many roles (I think you'll not hit the limit on `JOIN`ed tables). At the query plan queries may be merged by the optimizer (it may ignore brackets you've placed)

Answer (score 0):

1. In Oracle, `AS` between a table identifier or a subquery and the alias is invalid syntax. In ANSI SQL it is optional but in Oracle it is forbidden.

   Remove the two `AS` keywords.
2. Once you fix that then you will find that you have a `JOIN` between the two sub-queries and no `ON` clause for the join condition.

   Change the `WHERE` clause to an `ON` clause for the join.

```sql
select s.name
from   (
         select *
         from   students
                join friends on students.id=friends.id
                join packages on friends.id=packages.id
       ) s
       join (
         select *
         from   students
                join friends on students.id=friends.id
                join packages on friends.id=packages.id
       ) b
       on  (   s.salary<b.salary
           and s.Friend_ID=b.ID)
order by b.salary;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3ef6ddf3f4ee0d10ab4acfa58f81b524)*

Comment: Then it will complain that `b.id` is invalid identifier or that column is ambigously defined at least because `b` has three tables with `id` column (though it's quite strange model where IDs in semantically different tables mean the same, except when it is a class inheritance and some student is a package also)

Comment: @astentx Surprisingly, it does not complain about that. I've added a working fiddle to the answer.

Comment: It's especially surprising because it begin to complain if you remove one `package` table from join in the second subquery: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f21d276444fa8c1fa3fc405f439de7c7). Nothing to say)